# pyautogui. How to take a screenshot/scan of a scrollable field?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to use pyautogui to count how often a specific image appears on screen/on screenshot.
I know how to do it via the `locateOnScreen` function but my use case is a bit more tricky. The section where I want to count how often a specific image is found is scrollable. How could I possible count all the matches in the scrollable fiel?

For more details, the scrollable field is a collection of icons similar how you can see an folder full of images in windows explorer. I want to check how often a specific icon appears in this section.

I could take a screenshot/scan of the current view of the field and count the matches and tell the mouse to scroll but I have no idea how to know how far I need to scroll to take the next screenshot/scan to check for matches.

Do you guys have any idea how this could be done?